# поддержка optimistic\pessimistic locking в Java 7 SE

Tags: java, concurrency

Поддерживает ли Java SE 7 сабж ? Я не нашел такого(

Comment: Что вы конкретно имеете в виду под locking? `synchronized`-доступ? Блокирование в базе данных?

Comment: Если это про базы данных, то этот loking он и в африке loking. Хоть в java 7 se, хоть в визуал бейсике, везде поддерживается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то поддерживает. [Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html).

Comment: только это не SE

Comment: На автомате воспринял как EE, но видимо автора удовлетворил ответ.

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko да